# HTML::TagFilter command line vs apache

Tags: linux, perl, apache

I installed `HTML::TagFilter` from CPAN on a Fedora machine

This snippet works just fine on the command line :

```
my $tf = new HTML::TagFilter; 
$tf->deny_tags( { TABLE => {style => ["BORDER-BOTTOM"]} }); 
$tf->deny_tags( { TABLE => {prevstyle => ['any']} }); $str = $tf->filter($str);
```

But when the same code is run on Apache, I am getting this error:

```
[Fri Dec 14 16:11:48 2012] [error] Can't locate object method "new" via
package "HTML::TagFilter" at 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/HTML/TagFilter.pm line 320.
```

What could be the source of this error?

Comment: What version of `HTML::TagFilter` are you running? In [v1.03](https://metacpan.org/source/WROSS/HTML-TagFilter-1.03/TagFilter.pm), the referenced line would be calling the constructor of the superclass, in this case `HTML::Parser`. However, the error message doesn't *quite* match that (or if it does, I find this interesting). Then, are you running the same perl version on the command line and on the server? Also, call your `new` like `HTML::TagFilder->new`, rather than putting the `new` first. It is a class method, not a keyword.

Comment: Hi Moritz 
I am running the same version of perl on both. I am running version 1.03 of HTML::TagFilter.
Thanks

Comment: Such an error would normally be thrown if you call a method on a nonexistant package. However, this error is thrown *inside* the package in question, even if it should complain that `HTML::Parser` could not be found. Confusing. Could you post a minimal, yet complete example of code that triggers the error in Apache? I would like to be able to reproduce the problem. Also, how are you running perl on the server: CGI, mod_perl, FastCGI? Especially mod_perl can introduce interesting issues.